# Using ´foreach´ in a checkbox form in PHP

Tags: php, forms, checkbox

I am having trouble with my form and the use of `foreach`. I am trying to get dynamic `Wordpress` pages converted into dynamic checkboxes but I just cannot seem to make it right.
I am not very good with php so I would love an example if you decide to give me an answer.

My code right now:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['options'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) {
            echo "Selected" . $checked[$i] . "<br/>";
        }
    }
?>

<form method="post" action="">
<?php
    settings_fields( 'myoption-group' );
    do_settings_sections( 'myoption-group' );

    $pages = get_pages(); 
    foreach ($pages as $page){
    $option = '<option value="' . get_page_link( $page->ID ) . '">';
    $option .= $page->post_title;
    $option .= '</option>';
    echo "<input type='checkbox' name='options[]' value='$page->term_id' $option";
    echo $post->get_page;
    echo '<br>';
    }

    submit_button( 'Creëer pagina', 'primary', 'formSubmit' );
?>
</form>
```

The form works as meant to be, it is the piece of php above it that gives trouble. I only see: Selected when I press submit. Nothing about the page name that is currently selected. Any help would be most welcome!

EDIT:
Here is a screenshot of what I currently see:
http://www.idodesigns.nl/ehen/media/image.png

Another EDIT:
As requested more clarification. In the screenshot (http://www.idodesigns.nl/ehen/media/image.png) I clicked two checkboxes and then pressed the submit button. The output is: twice 'Selected'. After the 'Selected' I need php to repeat WHICH pages were actually selected. So it should be like: Selected, pagename , 
.

Changing $checked[$i] with $option unfortunately did not change anything to the result.

Comment: What does it currently do? What do you want it to do? What have you tried to do to make it work? I think a lot of people dislike questions of the form "Here is a dump of code - please fix it for me"

Comment: I am sorry, I cant find out how to edit my post above >_>. Currently it just says: selected. I do not mean to dump my stuff somewhere.. I just hoped a sharp eye saw the mistake I made. Already spend hours on this alone, haha ^^.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your PHP, you are referencing `$checked[$i]`, which doesn't exist.
I believe if you change it to this, it should work:

```
<?php
    if(isset($_POST['options'])) {
        foreach ($_POST['options'] as $option) {
            echo "Selected" . $option . "<br/>";
        }
    }
?>
```

In this instance, `$option` will be the value of the input, i.e. `$page->term_id`.

There does seem to be something funny going on with your markup too. It seems you haven't ended the input tag with a `>`, and I'm not sure what the purpose of the `<option>` tag is.

Edit:

So, if you want to have a label for your checkbox, you shouldn't be using the `<option>` tag, but rather it should be `<label>`.

From my understanding, you want the form to submit the page titles that have been checked. In that case, the value of the input needs to be set to the page title.

So, have a look at the changes I have made to your form (I've removed `echo $post->get_page;` because I don't believe that value existed at all):

```
<form method="post" action="">
<?php
    settings_fields( 'myoption-group' );
    do_settings_sections( 'myoption-group' );

    $pages = get_pages(); 
    foreach ($pages as $page){
        echo "<input type='checkbox' name='options[]' value='$page->post_title'>";
        echo "<label>$page->post_title</label>";
        echo "<br/>";
    }

    submit_button( 'Creëer pagina', 'primary', 'formSubmit' );
?>
</form>
```

Comment: I think you are right with replacing checked for $options. It still does not work but maybe that has to do with the option tag doing it wrong. I do get checkboxes and the page name with that though so I really wonder why I cant get the same in the posted results! Also I tried adding > somewhere in the line but the code keeps breaking or the > gets displayed after every page name. :p No idea where that should be put!

Comment: So are you looking to have a checkbox, with the title of the page next to it? When you submit the form, what value do you wish to receive? What is the use of `get_page_link( $page->ID )`?

Comment: I edited my question and added a screenshot: http://www.idodesigns.nl/ehen/media/image.png . <-thats what I have right now. I need to know the names of the pages so I can select certain pages on my Wordpress site. Then when I know the names I want to use I want to put the names in a new file (but I am not that far yet, I just need the output to also contain the name of the page so I know which is checked)

Comment: @Folthan I think I lost the point a little bit. Can you please formulate the expected result and add it to the question?

Comment: @Jack You made it work! You are my hero, I spend so much time in this but it is like French to me. Thanks for taking the time to understand the problem!

Comment: @Alexey Thanks a lot for spending time to help me, I am sorry that I was so unclear for you. jack solved my problem and it works now.

Comment: No problem @Folthan, glad it worked for you. I'm sure that as you work more on it, things will become clearer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you want a checkbox to be rendered for each WordPress page, I think you need to add `<input type=checkbox>` insted of `<option>` tag:

```
$pages = get_pages(); 
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $option = '<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"page' . $page->ID . '\">' . get_page_link( $page->ID );
    echo $option;
    echo '<br>';
}
```

Comment: You might be right with this comment, although it doesn't seem to work because there is a coding error in your code. Sublime shows the code breaking around page->ID. I tried fixing it but I don't see the error :(.

Comment: @Folthan I can't see compilation issue, AFAIK this code complies PHP syntax.. Maybe you can post error output?

Comment: Thanks for replying so soon. When I put it in sublime, it gets discolored (screenshot) idodesigns.nl/2/code-error.png . And when I use it like you say (replace my piece of code with yours) it displays nothing in Wordpress. (I also made a screenshot of my code as how it is now, and where you can see it just outputting 'selected'  http://www.idodesigns.nl/ehen/media/image.png

Comment: @Folthan the hightlight revealed my fail :) Try this updated code.

Comment: Wah it changed a lot but this was not what I was after! http://www.idodesigns.nl/2/second-try.png The checkboxes morphed into textfields and the names transformed into the links. And the thing that I wanted to change (on top: Selected) did not get repaired by it (even when I replace this line: echo "Selected" . $option . "<br/>";  to include: $option